# Invalid argument supplied for foreach();

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting this error,

Invalid argument supplied for foreach();
Undefined variable: rows........error in view line no 13.....

pls help me..i dont know wher is the error

**1.controller**

```
function customer_area() {

  $this->load->model('cus_model');

  $data['rows']=$this->cus_model->cusall();

  $this->load->view('customer_view',$data);

}
```

**2.models**

```
function cusall() {     
  $q = $this->db->get('customer');        
  $this->db->select('*');
  if($q->num_rows()>0) {    
    foreach($q->result() as $rows){      
      $data[]=$rows;
    }
    return $data;
  }
}`
```

**3.views**

```
<table border="1" height="200" width="200" bordercolor="#003366">
      <tr><th>ID</th></td><th>NAME</th><th>Type</th><th>Address</th><th>Mobile</th><th>Skype_Id</th><th>Email</th><th colspan="2">Actiom</th></tr>

      foreach($rows as $r)

    {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>". $r->id ."</td>";
      echo "<td>". $r->name ."</td>";
      echo "<td>". $r->type ."</td>";
      echo "<td>". $r->address ."</td>";
      echo "<td>". $r->mobile ."</td>";
      echo "<td>". $r->skype_id ."</td>";
      echo "<td>". $r->email ."</td>";
      echo "<td>". anchor('customer/input/'.$r->id,'Edit') ."</td>";    
      echo "<td>". anchor('customer/del/'.$r->id,'Delete') ."</td>";
      echo "</tr>"; 
      echo "<br>"; 
      }


      ?>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your model, return $q->result() instead of looping through and putting the rows in an array.

actually you can pretty much cut it down to this:

new function:

```
function cusall()       
{
    $q = $this->db->get('customer');
    return $q->result();
}
```

Comment: edited.  this way it either returns a result object that your foreach will loop through, or a false which will never let the foreach trgger

Comment: you shouldnt need to change the view at all.

Comment: replace your model function with the one i wrote.  you can verify its retrieving things from the db by using var_dump($data['rows']);exit; in your controller before you load the view